# Powershell Regex - Capture Multiple Strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I've been at this all day and still trying to understand regex. Any help would be appreciated.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is capture sentences in a string. example:

Criteria: this is the first criteria.
blah blah blah blah
Criteria: this is the second criteria.

I can use the regex statement of `$string -match "Criteria(?<data>.*)"` and it will match up to the first match, and all the rest with the .* but i would like to be able to group the two as to reference them later.
also, this is in PowerShell
thanks!

Comment: `()` create a capture group. If you don’t name them (using `(?<Name>)` syntax), then they are named 1,2, etc. So `$string -match '(criteria)(.*)'` will return true for successful match and false otherwise. A true result updates `$matches` automatic variable with the matched text. So `$matches.1` and `$matches.2` are your capture group results. 1 is `criteria` and 2 is the result of `.*`

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! This helped alot and i was able to get it working. just needed that last piece of the puzzle to understand the grouping.

Comment: You may wanna try this: https://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: Can the answer be added as an answer and then be accepted, so it doesn't look like this question is still open? I don't get this trend for sticking practical solutions in the comments. It's a little annoying to click on something "unanswered" when it's been sorted. Also, for anyone looking for solutions to similar questions, they'll skip over this one.

Answer (score 2):

As requested, the comment converted to answer:

In PowerShell (and most regex engines), `()` is a grouping mechanism that creates a capture group. If you use the syntax `(?<name>)`, the capture group will be named `name`. Otherwise, each set of parentheses that has a successful match is assigned a capture group number. The capture group numbering starts with 1 and increments upward by 1. The leftmost open `(` encompasses capture group 1 if there is a match. The second open `(` encompasses capture group 2 if there is a match. This pattern continues until there are no more groupings. Capture group `0` is the entire match.

`-match` is the PowerShell regex matching operator. By default, it does a single match and won't return multiple, complete matches. So once the entire regex string has been matched successfully, it will return to the prompt. If the left-hand side (LHS) of `-match` is a single string, then `-match` will return `True` if the match is successful. Otherwise, `False` is returned. When there is a successful match, the `$matches` automatic variable is updated with the match contents. `$matches` is a hash table with keys that are named the same as the capture group name.

If the LHS of the `-match` operator is an array, then successful matches will return the array elements that contain the successful match.

**Examples**

```
# Example: Successful Match Stops Parsing
'hi hey howdy' -match 'h\w+'
$matches.0 # returns hi since hi matched the complete regex string. it won't keep matching hey and howdy

# Example: Unnamed Capture Groups
'hi hey howdy' -match '(hi).*(ho.*)'
$matches.1 # returns hi
$matches.2 # returns howdy
$matches.0 # returns hi hey howdy

# Example: Unnamed Capture Groups With Nested Parentheses
'hi hey howdy' -match '((hi).*)(ho.*)'
$matches.1 # returns hi hey 
$matches.2 # returns hi
$matches.3 # returns howdy

# Example: Mixing named and unnamed capture groups
'hi hey howdy' -match '(?<first>hi)(.*)'
$matches.first # returns hi
$matches.1 # returns  hey howdy. capture group 1 is used because unnamed group numbering starts at 1

# Example: Capture group 1 is null and will not be added as a key to $matches!
'hi hey howdy' -match '(hello)*(hey)'
$matches.1 # returns nothing or an error on strict mode 2 or higher
$matches.2 # returns hey

# Example: LHS is an array
# returns array element 1: hello
'array element 0: hi hey howdy','array element 1: hello' -match 'hel'
```

---

Note that `$matches` is not updated or erased when there is an unsuccessful match. `$matches` is also not updated when the LHS is an array. You can also use conditional statements to update `$matches` as well. See below:

```
if ('hi hey howdy' -match 'hi') {
    $matches.0 # returns hi since the if statement is true
}
if ('hi hey howdy' -match 'z') {
    $matches.0 # returns nothing since the if statement is false
}
$matches.0 # returns hi because last -match attempt was false!
```